# How to change tmux logs directory from current directory to something else

Tags: tmux

> $ man tmux
>
> ...
>
> `-v` Request verbose logging. Log messages will be saved into `tmux-client-PID.log` and `tmux-server-PID.log` files in the current directory, where PID is the PID of the server or client process. If `-v` is specified twice, an additional `tmux-out-PID.log` file is generated with a copy of everything tmux writes to the terminal.

I'm just curious if anyone knows if there is some way to specify (by environment variable or some other way) some directory other than the "current directory" where the logs should be written to.

I wasn't able to find this in the documentation.